# Implementing Constraints in OPL Using CPLEX

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, modeling, opl

I've been working on addressing a specific constraint in OPL and attempted to write code to solve it. However, it's not functioning as expected. Could anyone provide guidance on the correct approach to do that.

Here is the constraint:

[image: constraint image]

The full code of the model in OPL : [Edited], the constraint is the second one :

```
// Example data
range J = 1..5;
range R = 1..3;
range T = 1..10;
int P[J] = [0,1,2,3,4]; 
int d[J] = [1, 1, 3, 5, 2];
int EF[J] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1];
int LF[J] = [2, 3, 4, 6, 2];
int Tbar = sum(j in J) d[j];

// Resource usage matrix
int u[J][R] = [[1, 0, 2],
               [1, 1, 1], 
               [1, 1, 0], 
               [2, 0, 3], 
               [1, 1, 2]];

// Resource availability
int a[R]= [1,2,3];

// Decision Variables
dvar boolean x[J][T];

dexpr int CT = sum(j in J, t in EF[j]..LF[j])t*x[j][t];
minimize CT;

subject to {
  forall(j in J)
     sum (t in EF[j]..LF[j]) x[j][t] == 1;
  forall(j in J, i in {P[j]}) //no job must be started before all its predecessors have been completed.
     sum (t in EF[j]..LF[j]:t in T) ((t - d[j]) * x[j][t]) - 
     sum (t in EF[i]..LF[i]:t in T) t * x[i][t] >= 0;
  forall(r in R, t in 1..Tbar) {
     sum(j in J) u[j][r] * sum(q in maxl(t, EF[j])..minl(t + d[j] - 1, LF[j])) x[j][q] <= a[r];
  }
}
```

I've attempted to apply my knowledge in OPL to address this issue, but I'm encountering difficulties. I would appreciate any advice on how to resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful to expand your questions to include a complete [mre], i.e. to include both inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs. Simply stating that your code doesn't work always runs the risk of your question being closed as it "Needs Debugging Details".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get many out of bounds

The following model works better

```
range J = 0..5;
range R = 1..3;
range T = 1..10;
int P[J] = [0,1,2,3,4]; 
int d[J] = [1, 1, 3, 5, 2];
int EF[J] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1];
int LF[J] = [2, 3, 4, 6, 2];



dvar int x[J][T];
subject to {
  forall(j in J, i in {P[j]})
    sum (t in EF[j]..LF[j]:t in T) ((t - d[j]) * x[j][t]) - 
    sum (t in EF[i]..LF[i]:t in T) t * x[i][t] >= 0;    
}
```

and later on with your second model, the following works fine

```
// Example data
range J = 0..5;
range R = 1..3;
range T = 1..10;
int P[J] = [0,1,2,3,4]; 
int d[J] = [1, 1, 3, 5, 2];
int EF[J] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1];
int LF[J] = [2, 3, 4, 6, 2];
int Tbar = sum(j in J) d[j];

// Resource usage matrix
int u[J][R] = [[1, 0, 2],
               [1, 1, 1], 
               [1, 1, 0], 
               [2, 0, 3], 
               [1, 1, 2]];

// Resource availability
int a[R]= [1,2,3];

// Decision Variables
dvar boolean x[J][T];

dexpr int CT = sum(j in J, t in EF[j]..LF[j]:t in T)t*x[j][t];
minimize CT;

subject to {
  forall(j in J)
     sum (t in EF[j]..LF[j]:t in T) x[j][t] <= 1;
  forall(j in J, i in {P[j]}) //no job must be started before all its predecessors have been completed.
     sum (t in EF[j]..LF[j]:t in T) ((t - d[j]) * x[j][t]) - 
     sum (t in EF[i]..LF[i]:t in T) t * x[i][t] >= 0;
  forall(r in R, t in 1..Tbar) {
     sum(j in J) u[j][r] * sum(q in maxl(t, EF[j])..minl(t + d[j] - 1, LF[j])) x[j][q] <= a[r];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlexFleischer, 
I've encountered an issue with integrating the provided solution into the model; unfortunately, it isn't functioning as expected. I've made adjustments to my original post and included the complete code for the model, which is intended for the Resource-Constrained Project Scheduling Problem (RCPSP).

Comment: For RCPSP you should have a look at CPOptimizer within CPLEX : examples/opl/sched_rcpsp